# Action dispatches successfully, payload reaches the reducer but the state remains the same. React+Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I made an action to set my current page for pagination in my table. The action is dispatched successfully and the correct payload reaches the reducer as seen the redux dev tools but the state doesnt change. I have no clue why it is happening. All my actions are working fine but this time i am facing this issue.
This is my action->

```
import { SET_CURRENT_PAGE } from "./types";

export const setCurrentPage = page => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_PAGE,
    page
  };
};
```

This is my reducer

```
import { SET_CURRENT_PAGE } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  currentPage: 1
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.payload) {
    case SET_CURRENT_PAGE: {
      return {
           ...state,
           currentPage:action.page
       };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I am calling this action in my table component. The action is dispatched successfully from there. I dont know why the state is not updating.
[Redux-dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPu9T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small mistake in your code, change the `action.payload` to `action.type` in the switch statement.

Try this.

```
import { SET_CURRENT_PAGE } from "../actions/types";
const initialState = {
  currentPage: 1
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_PAGE: {
      return {
           ...state,
           currentPage:action.page
       };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding payload in your action like below

```
import { SET_CURRENT_PAGE } from "./types";

export const setCurrentPage = page => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_PAGE,
    payload: page
  };
};
```

Use type for switch case and payload for setting the state like

```
import { SET_CURRENT_PAGE } from "../actions/types";
const initialState = {
  currentPage: 1
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_PAGE: {
      return {
           ...state,
           currentPage:action.payload
       };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```